# How can I batch rename all files that match a pattern in Linux?

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression, filenames, rename

I have folder which contains *many* `.mkv` files that I'd like to rename without having to manually do so.

The pattern is this:

```
...
[XVC]_Control_-_10_-_Doctors_[SCB055Y].mkv
[XVC]_Control_-_11_-_Engineers_[50OPZ00].mkv
...
```

I'd like the results to be:

```
...
Control-10-Doctors.mkv
Control-11-Engineers.mkv
...
```

---

I've tried using `find` and piping it through `sed` and `tr`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
find . -iname "*.mkv" -exec sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' {} \;
find . -type f "*mkv" | sed 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' | tr -d '_'
find . "*.mkv" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' | tr -d '_'
find . -iname "*.mkv" -exec rename 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' .mkv '{}' \;
find . -iname "*.mkv" -exec rename -n 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' {} ";"
```

And several others, but none seem to work. I find it puzzling that the command command below works:

```
(input)
echo '[XVC]_Control_-_10_-_Doctors_[SCB055Y].mkv' | sed 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' | tr -d '_'`

(output)
Control-10-Doctors.mkv
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
$ file $(which rename)
/usr/bin/rename: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=d7b5a08ee8556c59dbdda26e998e20d4762c2bbc, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

```
rename -n 's/\[.+?\]//g; s/_//g' *mkv
rename: not enough arguments
Try 'rename --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Which Linux? Do you have perl rename?

Comment: @terdon I'm using Fedora 36. I'm sure I have `perl` and the `rename` command installed, if that's what you're thinking of.

Comment: No, I am wondering if the `rename` command you used is the one from `util-linux` or if it is the perl script often installed as `rename` on Debian-based systems. What does `file $(which rename)` return? Do you have either `prename` or `perl-rename` installed? See [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230)

Comment: Sometimes an installation is convoluted and `file $(which rename)` will only show a link, and you have to follow that link to find what kind of program it points to (sometimes in several steps). For this reason I made the shellscript `what-about`, that does that job for us. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736432/how-to-get-the-location-of-a-program-in-ubuntu-terminal/1413975#1413975).

Comment: @sudodus thanks for the script. I don't use a Debian-based distro, though (Fedora), so I don't have `dpkg` installed; is  there an alternative I can use to substitute the command inside the script?

Comment: @sudodus I tried re-running the script and I get the following errors: `what-about: line 73: file: command not found`; `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/rename`; `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *rename*`.

Comment: [This link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/663841/dnf-how-to-i-check-which-package-installed-a-specific-package) may help you (to use `dnf`)

Comment: I see from your edited [original] question, that it is not perl rename, but a compiled program. You should read its manual, `man rename` in order to check which options and commands that are relevant. They might be [slightly?] different from what should be used in perl rename.

Comment: If you have util-linux rename, the syntax is very different from perl rename. At the end of `man rename` you might find information telling which version of rename it is. Or run `rename -V`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work with perl-rename (called `rename` or `prename` or `perl-rename` depending on your distribution):

```
$ rename -n 's/\[.*?\]|_//gs' ./*.mkv
[XVC]_Control_-_10_-_Doctors_[SCB055Y].mkv -> Control-10-Doctors.mkv
[XVC]_Control_-_11_-_Engineers_[50OPZ00].mkv -> Control-11-Engineers.mkv
```

If that gives you the output you want, run it again without the `-n` to actually rename the files.

Alternatively, write a little loop:

```bash
find . -iname "*.mkv" -print0 |
    while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
        newName=$(printf -- '%s\n' "$file" | perl -pe 's/\[.*?\]|_//gs')
        echo mv -- "$file" "$newName"
    done
```

If that looks right, remove the `echo` and run it again to actually rename the files.

---

Your commands didn't work for various reasons.

1. `find . -iname "*.mkv" -exec sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' {} \;`

   This one is running the `sed` command on the file itself, so it would only make changes to the file's contents, not the name. And not even that since you aren't using `-i` which means that it just prints the changed contents to standard output.
2. `find . -type f "*mkv" | sed 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' | tr -d '_'`

   Here, the `find` is printing file names but those are just passed as text (a stream) to `sed` which modfies its input, but doesn't alter the file name. It's the same as `echo foo | sed 's/f/b/'`. That won't rename a file named `foo` if one happens to be there.
3. `find . "*.mkv" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' | tr -d '_'`

   Here, the `sed` is being run on the files again, so it is basically the same as above except that it would actually modify the file if any of its contents match. As these are binary files, it is unlikely but not impossible that you have actually modified them.
4. `find . -iname "*.mkv" -exec rename 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' .mkv '{}' \;`

   This one is actually capable of renaming the files, but since you are passing the string `.mkv` as the first argument to the `rename` command, it is trying to rename a file called `.mkv`. As you presumably have no such file, it does nothing. The second argument, `'{}'`, is ignored. This would have worked:

   ```
   find . -iname "*.mkv" -exec rename 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' {} \;
   ```

   But it would have renamed the files to `_Control_-_10_-_Doctors_.mkv` and `_Control_-_11_-_Engineers_.mkv` since you weren't handling the `_` in that one.
5. `find . -iname "*.mkv" -exec rename -n 's/\[[^][]*\]//g' {} ";"`

   This one should have worked! It would just not have done the correct renaming, just as described in 4 above.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, very interesting read. I encountered an error, though. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @telometto you're welcome, but that isn't an error. It's as I said in the comments of your question: that's the rename executable from the util Linux package, you need to find perl-rename instead. I assumed that's what you were using because you were using its syntax. See the link I gave you and look for the right name in the red hat repositories. It's probably `perl-rename`.

Comment: I installed `prename`, executed the command you gave me, and it worked a charm! Again, many, many thanks!

Comment: @gilles the command is called `perl-rename` on many systems. It isn't "Perl's rename", as in the rename of perl, it's a rename script, written in perl.

Comment: Perl's rename script if you prefer :)

Comment: I prefer to use the actual name, really. It's `perl-rename` on my Arch and I think also on red hat derived systems. And I'm not sure if it's the one that ships with perl. There are at least three different ones: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/22222

Comment: What is important, is to 'discard' the one from `util-linux` like Debian drops, that looks few used around. Perl's family of `rename` commands are all very close enough for basic usage. AFAIK all implements `-n`